# Algorithm to get short path between given currency exchange rates

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm working on an integration process that requires the currency conversion between a list of values in specific currency to a concrete given currency.

For this process will exists 2 files, one containing the exchange rates and other containing the prices with the origin currency.

The exchange rates files looks like this:

```
Text:USDtoEUR;Origin:USD;Destination:EUR;Value:0.7
Text:EURtoCAD;Origin:EUR;Destination:CAD;Value:0.5
```

The file containing the prices with the origin currency (and also the target currency) looks like this:

```
Index:0;TargetCurrency:CAD
Index:1;Description:Product1;Value:150;Currency:EUR
Index:2;Description:Product2;Value:3;Currency:USD
```

For this specific case there is no direct way to convert from USD to CAD, so I need to first convert it to another currency present in the file that has CAD exchange rate (EUR) and then convert it to CAD.

This is a very basic scenario, but I'm guessing those files can contain more complex ones, where maybe it's required to convert 2 or 3 times before reaching the target currency.

What I'm planning to do is to insert the content of the exchange rates file into a SQL Server table and then start a very manual process of looking records containing the target currency... but I've never faced this scenario and don't know if this could be an acceptable approach in terms of speed/performance, that's why I'm wondering if there is a standard algorithm or data structure best suited for this process.

I will appreciate your help

Comment: This sounds a lot like Dijkstra's algorithm, where the cost of each vertex is either a constant value, or based on the exchange rate.

Comment: _"SQL Server table"_ So you ask for a SQL solution?

Comment: Personally I'd want to do this in-memory rather than in a database, but people have implemented Dijkstra's algorithm in T-SQL

Comment: I was thinking about a little in-mem Graph DB ... is there?

Comment: Viva Dijkstra.  You can check also [QuickGraph](https://github.com/YaccConstructor/QuickGraph).

Comment: @Rango Not really a sql approach, Im guessing it's possible but its just an idea

Answer (score 0):

If you need to take the currency conversion rate into consideration to find an optimal conversion path, you would use **Bellman-Ford Algorithm** .
This [link](https://www.thealgorists.com/Algo/ShortestPaths/Arbitrage) may help you.

But, if the performance of the conversion is matters, you need to use an algorithm to find the shortest path between two nodes (visiting fewer nodes, regardless of the conversion cost) like **BFS** or **DFS**
(means traversing the tree to find the shortest path between two nodes(two currencies).